# Can I get thread counts remotely with Immunity Debugger

Tags: immunity-debugger, thread, remote

I am debugging a program on a Windows server with Immunity debugger.

Immunity debugger offers a remote command line client. I can do basic tasks through this command line.

But is there a way to get threads count?